# Prove $x<y \Rightarrow x+z < y+z$ with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{K}$ when $\mathbb{K}$ is an ordered field.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Prove $x<y \Rightarrow x+z < y+z$ with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{K}$ when $\mathbb{K}$ is an ordered field.

My attempt:

$x<y \Leftrightarrow x+0<y+0 \Leftrightarrow  x+(z+(-z))< y+ (z+(-z)$

$\Leftrightarrow x+(z+(-z))+z < y+(z+(-z))+z $

$\Leftrightarrow x+z < y+z \quad \Box$

Comment: Usually, this is one of the two conditions in the **definition** of an (totally) ordered field.  So what is your definition of an ordered field?

Comment: Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. A subset $\mathbb{K}^{+}$ is an ordered field if: $x$ is either $x\in \mathbb{K}^{+}$, $x=0$, or $-x\in \mathbb{K}^{+}$. Secondly, if $x,y\in \mathbb{K}^{+}$, then $x+y, x\cdot y \in \mathbb{K}^{+}$

Comment: And, given your correct definition, what is the definition of “$x<y$”?

Comment: $x<y$, if $y-x \in \mathbb{K}^{+}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $x<y$ means that $y-x\in\mathbb K^+$. But then, if $x<y$ and $z\in\mathbb K$,\begin{align}x+z<y+z&\iff(y+z)-(x+z)\in\mathbb K^+\\&\iff y-x\in\mathbb K^+,\end{align}which is true.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why can't I prove it like in my question?

Comment: Because when you write$$x+(z+(-z))< y+ (z+(-z)\Longleftrightarrow x+(z+(-z))+z < y+(z+(-z))+z,$$you are assuming what you are trying to prove (you are adding $z$ to both sides of the inequality).

Answer (score 0):

Your step $x + (z+(-z)) < y + (z+(-z)) \Rightarrow x + (z+(-z)) + z < y + (z+(-z)) + z$ is exactly what you are trying to prove.